# MetroTabItem Mahapps does not trigger the event MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, tabitem

I am realizing a panel with two tabs , the problem is that the MouseDown event is not triggered , I applied but not goes .
And ' possible to adopt a solution to activate the click ?
Thank you in advance

```
<controls:MetroTabItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="140" Header="Inviti" MouseDown="MetroTabItem_MouseDown_1">
  <surface:SurfaceScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="207" PanningMode="Both">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=participantsInviteTrue}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,2,0,0" Height="30" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#D9D9D9" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,2,0,3" Width="30" Height="30" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
                  <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource ="{Binding Base64Image, Converter={StaticResource Base64ImageConverter}}"></ImageBrush>
                  </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                  <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                      <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                      <Binding Path="LastName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="showInfoUser" Tag="{Binding PPID}" Grid.Column="1" Width="28" Height="28" IsEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
                  <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/Images/icon-pending@2x.png"></ImageBrush>
                  </Button.Background>
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </surface:SurfaceScrollViewer>
</controls:MetroTabItem>
```

in my project i use wpf without patterne and c# from codebehind.
I think it does not work because the MetroTabItem already triggers an event to click to switch between tabs , no solution and add an event to click?

Comment: same with me, mahapps doesn't trigger event mouseDown, still searching solution

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, using PreviewMouseDown event, it's like use MouseDown event.
See the explanation [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/61807025-d4c4-41e0-b648-b11183065009/mousedown-event-not-working-wpf?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an event when the tab is activated then use the `GotFocus` event because it can also be focused using an alt-key combination based on the title name. eg `Header="_Title"` can be activated with Alt-T. Also, touch screens and probably fricken lasers sometime in the future.